# Is there any framework in android equivalent to Apple's carekit and researchkit?

Tags: android, ios, researchkit, carekit

Looking for any alternative to Apple's CareKit and ResearchKit for android.

Answer (score 5):

You might wanna take a look at this http://researchstack.org/